# how to open ms access database in system which does not have ms office installed in c++

Tags: c++, ms-access, adodb

I have a tool that is developed in C++, it has ms access as a database. i am using ADODB to access the database. The tool works fine with the system which has MS office installed.

I am trying to run the tool in a system where MS office is not installed.
The Open db call is failing.

Can you please suggest me any solution for this problem ?

Comment: An obvious solution would be to install Access. :-) I don't know of any other way.

Comment: @BoPersson : I would like to run the tool in systems where MSoffice is not a required software.

Answer (score 0):

The Access application itself is not required for ADODB reading/writing of an Access database, but Office is required.

There are various projects that have had degrees of success in reverse engineering the mdb and accdb formats, but I'm not sure that they're robust enough for regular use. See [MDB Tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MDB_Tools) or [Jackcess](http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/)

You might want to consider exporting the tables to a CSV format and then querying those files, or importing them into an alternate database.

Comment: Thanks for the information. My requirement is to just read the entries from the mdb file.

Comment: can Data Access Objects (DAO) be used to solve this problem ??

Comment: I doubt it. Even if you can get ADO or DAO, or even RDO installed without Office, you'll still need the JET or Access Database Engine drivers...

Comment: To access .mdb file using any database abstraction library (ADO or DAO), any system should contain either msaccess installed in it or some of the dependent dll's installed. Can anyone suggest me, if i use a Sqlite database file (replacing mdb file) would help me in accessing the database without any specific installation in a system ?